# How to delete some records before X time in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel

I want to create a script that will automatically delete database records before `2 hours` on `time_start (DB field)`

[image: database screenshot]

But I don't know how to do it, I am new in Laravel

Thank you.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling

Comment: This is explained in the manual https://laravel.com/docs/scheduling

Comment: Why `groupBy` is not working? `::groupBy('time_start')->get()`